Python Reaching File optimization
I had a question about optimization on python.
I have a code for a jukebox. This jukebox plays lists of songs (eg. list 1 plays song 1, 2, 3, list 2 plays song 4, 5, 6 etc.)
Each of these lists have a different lenght. I first thought that it was easier to read a txt file that contains the list. Here is how it should have looked.

song1.wav song2.wav song3.wav
song4.wav song5.wav son6.wav
song7.wav
song8.wav song9.wav song10.wav song11.wav

Then, with a few line, I would be able to read the lenght of lists and the file names.
I then had another idea: put the list names in the file names, like shown below.
1_1.wav, 1_2.wav, ... , 2_4.wav, ...

So, I was wondering, which method was preferable. The first one seems easier to set up, but the second one seems most efficient. Am I right ? Any other opinions ?
Thanks ! :)

Why would method 2 be more efficient?

But also, "Premature optimisation is the root of all evil". Is it really gonna make even a slightest difference for your music playing program?

If you look for some more classy solution, I suggest creating sqlite database, or maybe easier .csv file. With all information needed. However, I agree with matszwecja - don't worry much now about efficiency, it should have little impact.  PS: @matszwecja by any chance are you polish chess player? ;)

@dankal444 I am Polish, yes, but I haven't played chess for a loooong time so I'm probably not the person you're thinking of :P

Thanks for your very quick awsers !
@dankal444, do you think that a CSV database is ok for around 85 text elements ? I also forgot to say that my program runs on a raspberry pi Pico with circuitpython, which constraints a lot my program! However, I use an SD for the audio files, so storage is not a problem.

@Z1scko Unless your program has actual performance problems (however you define them), it is way more important for it to be a) easily understood and b) easy to modify. Let's say you want to combine two lists into one. With approach 1 , all you's need to to is cut and paste one line in a file. In approach 2, the same would require renaming all files belonging to that playlist.

@matszwecja Alright, thank's, I think that I will stick to the first method, since indeed, the code will be more readable and flex.

@matszwecja just your name suggest polish chess player who knows "mat szewski" and made little change :)  @ Z1scko CSV files are often 100.000+ rows large, around 100 should not be a problem at all, even at Raspberry. For now focus on code readability, later on efficiency

@dankal444 Thank's for the good advice, I take notes !

Use an array to organize the .wav files into two sections.
JukeboxPlaylist = []

# This will let you read the file
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as file:
    wordCount = 0
    # Wav files 1-3
    sectionA = []
    # Wav files 4-...
    sectionB = []

    # for each line in ‘file’
    for line in file:
        # for each word in the line
        for word in line.split():
            # 'wordCount' keeps track of what word the program is on.
            wordCount = wordCount+1
            # if wordCount is less than four, it will add it to sectionA of the playlist
            if wordCount < 4:
                sectionA.append(word)
            # if the wordCount has exceeded four, then it will add it to sectionB.
            else:
                sectionB.append(word)

    # Adds both sectionA and sectionB to the final list.
    JukeboxPlaylist.append(sectionA)
    JukeboxPlaylist.append(sectionB)

This code will allow you to organize the wav files however you would like and it would still give you the same list output in JukeboxPlaylist. So you could have your original
song1.wav song2.wav song3.wav
song4.wav song5.wav son6.wav
song7.wav
song8.wav song9.wav song10.wav song11.wav

and get [[song1.wav, song2.wav, song3.wav], [song4.wav, ...]] or use your
1_1.wav, 1_2.wav, ... , 2_4.wav, ...

and also get [[1_1.wav, 1_2.wav, 1_3.wav], [2_4.wav, 2_5.wav, ...]]
In order to call a specific song, you would have to do JukeboxPlaylist[x][x] with the first brackets being either sectionA (0) or sectionB (1). The second set of brackets being the index of the song. Using this, you can create a for loop or function that will increase the index by one every time it finishes a song.
